# Is there a better way to get the names of all parent elements?

Tags: jquery, parents

To get the names of all parent elements?

```
 $(document).on('click', function(e){
    var parents = $(e.target).parents().map(function(){ 
        var $this = $(this),
            $id = $this.prop('id') ? '#'+$this.attr('id') : '',
            $class = $this.prop('class') ? '.'+$this.attr('class') : ''; 
        return this.tagName.toLowerCase()+$id+$class;
        }).get().join(" < ");
    prompt('The path to the element, Luke:',parents);
 });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shehovn/cdWXN/) with example.

**EDIT:** Nice! Thanks, guys! Updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shehovn/cdWXN/4/).

Comment: Why do you want another way to get all the parent elements?? Your way does not work?? :\

Comment: There always is a better way even my ways goes right ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works well, I've run some tests and none got to improve your current method.

Additionally to the suggestion provided by gion_13, I would suggest reversing the order of displaying the elements!

Depending on your goal, it might have a better readability from HTML to clicked element, by using [.reverse()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reverse.asp):

```
$(document).on('click', function(e){
  var parents = $(e.target).parents().map(function(){

    var $this  = $(this),
        $id    = $this.prop('id') ? '#'+$this.attr('id') : '',
        $class = $this.prop('class') 
                   ? '.'+$.trim($this.attr('class')).replace(/\s+/g,'.') 
                   : '';

    return this.tagName.toLowerCase()+$id+$class;

  }).get().reverse().join(" > ");

  prompt('The path to the element, Luke:',parents);
});
```

The Fiddle example [here!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/cdWXN/2/)

Answer (score 3):

It works ok and it's quite clear & straight-forrward. The only thing you could improve is adding a dot before each class :

```
$class = $this.prop('class') 
             ? '.'+$.trim($this.attr('class')).replace(/\s+/g,'.') 
             : '';
```

Here's a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cdWXN/1/